# How to enable only specific dates in Angular 5?

Tags: datepicker, angular5

I have set of dates and I want to enable only those dates in `<mat-datepicker>`.

```
"ListOfDates": [
      {
         "startDate": "2018-01-01T08:00:00"
      },
      {
         "startDate": "2018-01-02T08:00:00"
      },
      {
        "startDate": "2018-01-03T09:00:00",
      }]
```

This is my html code:

```
<mat-form-field>
     <input matInput
        [matDatepicker]="picker"
        [matDatepickerFilter]="dateFilter"
        placeholder="Choose a date">
     <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
     <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
 </mat-form-field>
```

In my `Component.ts` file:

```
@Component({...})
export class SomeComponent.ts {

    dateFilter = (date: Date) => date.getDate()

}
```

Can anyone help on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are going to need a custom validator. More details can be found here: https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview#date-validation

Essentially you give a function that takes in a date and returns a boolean indicating whether that date is valid. In your case you want to in your controller check if the given date is a member of your list. Here is a basic implementation:

HTML:

```
<mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
  <input matInput [matDatepickerFilter]="myFilter" [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Choose a date">
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

TS:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

/** @title Datepicker with filter validation */
@Component({
  selector: 'datepicker-filter-example',
  templateUrl: 'datepicker-filter-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['datepicker-filter-example.css'],
})
export class DatepickerFilterExample {
  validDates = {
    "2018-01-01T08:00:00": true,
    "2018-01-02T08:00:00": true
  }

  myFilter = (d: Date): boolean => {
    // Using a JS Object as a lookup table of valid dates
    // Undefined will be falsy.
    return validDates[d.toISOString()];
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply . I tried above code but it is not working :( . No dates are enabled, it should enable 01/01/2018 and 02/01/2018.

Comment: You may want to a breakpoint in the filter. Check to see if/why the comparison is returning false. I would expect it has to do with the hour field not matching or something. Print `d` and see what it looks like.

Comment: ah..yes, you are right. d.toISOString() is returning date as 2018-02-21T18:30:00.000Z but In my JSON, it is 2018-01-01T08:00:00. I just tried with added 0Z and it is working as expected. Thank you so much :)

Comment: No ptoblem. Though imo you should just drop everything after the date. d.toISOString().split('T')[0] would do that. It's a little cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

```
myFilter = (d: Date): boolean => {
  let enableFlag = false;
  this.ListOfDates.some((date) => {
    if (date.startDate === d) { // You can use any other comparison operator used by date object
      enableFlag = true;
      return true;
    }
  })
  return enableFlag;
}
```

Note: You will have to format the d and dates in ListOfDates to a standard format of your choice